# In C# how do I initiate a method to run postponed with ability to postpone further?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to run a delayed method in my code the way so that I could further control that "postponed method" (i.e. postpone it even more).

More specifically, I am doing this when reading data from serial port to ensure that the data has stopped flowing in. The data that I receive is rather unspecific so I can't rely on its length or some termination symbol. Instead, I want to use the DataReceived handler as usual and inside initiate the "process data" method as postponed for 200ms or so - but to postpone it again and again if further DataReceived handlers are firing.

So basically, my code would need to go something like this:

```
private string _serialPortCurrentReceivedDataBuffered = null;

private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string receivedData = ((SerialPort)sender).ReadExisting();

    if (_serialPortCurrentReceivedDataBuffered == null)
    {
        _serialPortCurrentReceivedDataBuffered = receivedData;
    }
    else
    {
        _serialPortCurrentReceivedDataBuffered += receivedData;
    }

    <THAT POSTPONED METHOD>.SetStartToTime(DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(200));
}

private <THAT POSTPONED METHOD>()
{
    string receivedData = _serialPortCurrentReceivedDataBuffered;
    _serialPortCurrentReceivedDataBuffered = null;
    
    <HANDLE RECEIVED DATA>
}
```

Is there a way to do so? I am working with .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Also, inside <THAT POSTPONED METHOD> I will need to manipulate the UI (WinForms), if that's of any consideration in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-5.0) to schedule a call to a method after a certain period of time. You could then use [`Timer.Change()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.change?view=net-5.0) to postpone the scheduled callback time. In order to manipulate the UI, you'd need a call to `Control.BeginInvoke()` though. Can you use async/await?

Comment: You could try using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200); which will make the thread sleep for 200 milliseconds.

Comment: Thread.Sleep(200); will allow your code to wait till 200 milliseconds and continue the execution.

Comment: You could consider Microsoft's [system.reactive] framework. Then you can do things like this: `source.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200.0)).Subscribe(x => { /* do stuff here */ });`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks! Timer did the trick for me.